# How can I redirect /api/* requests to another file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I've been using Laravel for my API server, however it takes alot of resources for tiny tasks and we want to write our API in a different framework. Unless I completely seperate our API for scalability purposes, can I temporarily redirect all `/api/*` requests to `api.php`?

This is our folder structure:

```
app
vendor
public
    index.php
    .htaccess
    api.php
```

This is our `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Excludes existing directories and files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just as a future note, Laravel 5 will have a route caching feature, which should help speed up requests: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/8

Comment: The problem isn't route caching, it is Laravel being extremely slow.

I've rewrote my API with Klein today and it only takes 3-10MS per request. Laravel was taking 70ms just for boot period alone and around 5MB of resources.

Anyway, `route:cache` is a very nonsense solution. I could put varnish in front of Laravel to serve those "static" pages and it wouldn't even load Laravel.

Anyway, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just below `R=301` rule you can add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^api/ api.php [L,NC]
```